# Where is the snapshot screen?

Tags: xcode, snapshot

I have two snapshots (created in Xcode using File, Create Snapshot) that I want to compare in Xcode. The documentation I've read shows how to compare the snapshots by selecting them in the snapshot window, but it doesn't explain how to get to the snapshot window. Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Organizer. Select Projects. Snapshots are listed below.

Comment: good to know. 5 Minute google time ? seems pretty efficient to me :)

Comment: @Volure, Yeah, but I didn't post the question in the first place until I had been looking already for an hour. Of course I found it right away when I posted the question. I'm still missing something basic, though. I've found where the snapshots are, and I can highlight two of them, but I can't figure out how to compare them to each other.

Comment: I think I stumbled across it. If I click one of the snapshots and then select Export Snapshot, a compare screen is displayed. This is not intuitive at all. I thought it would export the snapshot when I clicked Export Snapshot.

Comment: Hmm. I shall have to look into Snapshots now. If they allow that sort of viewing they will come in quite handy. I usually use my git repo. Xcode does an OK job on integrating git into the IDE. I especially like the "Blame" section.

Comment: Yeah. Git is good, but I didn't start my current project with git, and my attempt so far to add it didn't work. That's a task for another day. If you know of good instructions to add git to an existing project, let me know.

Comment: email me Ill hook you up. volure@gmail.com

Comment: was going to put it here, but its off topic